# Views: List of recent months containing nodes

Tags: views, uri

Using Drupal 7, views 7.x-3.0-beta3. I am trying to make a display containing a list of links which direct users to an archive page containing posts of that month (eg. all news messages posted in march 2011).

Tried to solve this with a contextual filter 'Created year + month',
which, when no parameter is given, gives a summary list of links like 'march 2011, december 2010' linking to the URL 'news/201103', 'news/201012'.

Is there a way to change the formatting of that URL to 'news/YYYY/MM' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create path alias to make the URL look how you want, but views need the year and month as a single argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_url_inbound_alter()` to rewrite the paths generated by the Year + Month argument. It's not pretty, but it gets the job done.

The following is for a view with year and month (and day!) arguments at `news/archive`:

```
function MODULENAME_url_inbound_alter(&$path, $original_path, $path_language) {
    $args = arg(NULL, $path);

    if (
        $args[0] === 'news' &&
        $args[1] === 'archive' &&
        !empty($args[2]) &&
        strlen($args[2]) === 6
    ) {
        $year = array(substr($args[2], 0, 4));
        $month = array(substr($args[2], 4, 2));
        $remaining = array_slice($args, 3);
        $new_args = array_merge($year, $month, $remaining);
        $path = 'news/archive/' . implode('/', $new_args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace Content: Created year + month with 2 separate contextual filters:

- Content: Created month
- Content: Created year

Comment: Thanks, but that results into a list of months, without years...